# Docker stuck on curriculum tutorial

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to follow Docker tutorial at https://docker-curriculum.com/. When it starts to talk about Dockerfile I can follow it and I could put the image to run. My output says:

> - Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL + C to quit)

Then I try to run the application on my browser - I'm using 192.168.99.100:8888 and 192.168.99.100:5000 and the only thing I get is a "can't reach this page"  message.

Does someone knows what to do at this stage? What is the correct address and the correct port?

Thanks

Comment: Run `docker ps` and check the id of the container. Then paste your output of `docker logs <container_id_or_name>` here. Is 192.168.99.100 your local IP address? Did you try to access localhost:8888 yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open http://localhost:8888 if that is the port you map on the host. (And that before pressing Ctrl+C to quit ;) )